# scp takes more time to copy and stalls

Tags: scp

I am using Ubuntu with a 2Mbps link. I would do `scp` to the Ubuntu cloud servers to copy a `.war` file which is 14MB. It used to take only 2 minutes to copy this `.war` file under `/tmp` of the cloud server. Now it takes more than 15 minutes.

While doing `scp` it stalls and restarts again. The `scp` progress looks like this:

```
app1.war                     15%    2320KB  61.3KB/s - stalled -^
```

Any tips? I'm asked to fix this soon.

The output of `tcpdump -n -n host my-dest-ip and port 22` is (I just stopped it with Ctrl+C)

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: If you try to copy that file to some other server than Ubuntu cloud, is that still slow? Try to first find if it's your uplink that stalls or if Ubuntu cloud is somehow limiting you.

Comment: yes it is slow for all 3 cloud servers

Comment: The problem was with my ISP. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be useful to find out if anything obvious is going wrong at the network level.  do you have root on either end?  can you do a tcpdump to isolate the scp datastream?

Comment: Yeah root is present. I don't have any idea of how to do tcpdump

Comment: on the source box, try "tcpdump -n -n host DESTINATION_BOX and port 22", replacing DESTINATION_BOX with the ip address of the destination box.  i should add that by "do you have root" i mean "do you have root access", which you will need to do a tcpdump.

Comment: Sorry!. As you said `it would be useful to find out if anything obvious is going wrong at the network leve` it was my ISP's problem.

Comment: Well, four cheers for you for coming back and letting us all know! Glad it's fixed, but if I were you, I'd spend a couple of hours learning to use tcpdump in the interim; it's an *extremely* useful tool for diagnosing problems like this (look for retransmissions, weird ICMP grumbles, that kind of thing).

Comment: I would like to copy your habits. I'll learn that. Thanks!